# add file name as header of column

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a directory with tables in txt format, and I'd like to add the file name as the header of the second column, for example:

file_1.txt

```
row_1 1 
row_2 0 
row_3 1  
row_4 1 
row_5 1 
row_6 1
```

output.txt

```
rows  file_1
row_1  1 
row_2  0 
row_3  1  
row_4  1 
row_5  1
```

I was thinking in something like this

```
sed 1 's/top_row/$file_name/1' < "$file";
```

Comment: you wouldn't want to name *all* of the output files `output.txt`; are you expecting the files to be updated "in-place"?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This writes out a line with `rows file_1.txt` and then cats out the entire file:

```
 echo "rows $file"; cat "$file"
```

If you want to drop the file extension from the output, as you've shown above, use `basename`:

```
 echo "rows $(basename $file .txt)"; cat "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in ./file_*.txt
do
  awk 'NR==1 { print "rows", FILENAME }; 1' "$file" > temp && mv temp "$file"
done
```

Alternatively, with a sed that supports `-i` for in-place editing:

```
for file in ./file_*.txt
do
  sed -i "1i\
rows $file" "$file"
done
```

Comment: You should only use `printf` with an explicit format string to protect yourself from unknown characters in the filename: `printf "rows\t%s\n", FILENAME` (imagine the filename is `foo%s.txt`) -- then again `print "rows", FILENAME` is simpler.

Comment: excellent point; thank, you, glenn -- I've incorporated it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `file_*.txt` would match all the files that you'd like to process, and that the files uses a tab character for delimiter:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
for filename in file_*.txt; do
    { printf 'rows\t%s\n' "$filename"; cat "$filename"; } >$tmpfile &&
    mv "$tmpfile" "$filename"
done
```

This would iterate over the matching filenames, and for each file would output a line containing the header followed by the contents of the file itself into a temporary file which, if all that went ok, then replaces the original file.

Note that this modifies the original files.  In your question you give one example and say that this should be outputted to `output.txt`, but it's unclear where to write the result for all the other files, so I went with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

some incrutable perl, just for fun

```
perl -i -pe '$.==1&&do{($f=$ARGV)=~s/\..*?$//;$_="rows $f\n$_"};close ARGV if eof' *.txt
```

Comment: can you explain this code? thx